# How to create a new key and add or append an array of objects on AWS DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have this object in my dynamodb table which looks like

```
{
  "id": "b31de483"
}
```

I want to add another object that looks like

```
{
  "id": "b31de483",
  "players": [{"playerId": "1234"}]
}
```

This is my code

```
const addPlayerToGame = async (gameId, playerId) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_GAMES_TABLE, 
    Key: {
        id: gameId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set players = list_append(if_not_exists(players, :players)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':players': {
        "L": [
          { "S": playerId }
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  return await documentClient.update(params);
}
```

This throws an error but I cannot understand how to fix it. I am looking at documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateItem-property)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
const addPlayerToGame = async (gameId, playerId) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_GAMES_TABLE, 
    Key: {
        id: gameId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'set players = list_append(players, :players)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':players': [{
        "playerId": playerId 
      }]
    }
  };

  return await documentClient.update(params).promise();
}
```